# How can I avoid repeating myself in the following JavaScript situation?

Tags: javascript, dry

In the scenario below, I have a boolean value.  Depending on the result, I call the exact same function with the only difference being the number of parameters.

```
var myBoolean = ...

if (myBoolean) {
    retrieveData(param1, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // process
    });
}
else {
    retrieveData(param1, param2, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // process
    });
}
```

At the moment it feels like I'm repeating a lot of code unnecessarily.  Is there a way to consolidate this so I'm not repeating the same thing?

Comment: Why not always call the function with 3 arguments? In case you do not need to send in the param2 value, you can send a null. Then in your `retrieveData` function, you can check if param2 is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the situation is as simple as this, then just save the repeated function in a variable:

```
var myBoolean = ...
var callback = function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // process
}
if (myBoolean) {
    retrieveData(param1, callback);
}
else {
    retrieveData(param1, param2, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass an object with `param2` equal to `false` when `myBoolean` is `true`

```
retrieveData({ 
       param1: param1,
       param2: (!myBoolean)? param2 : false 
     }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // process
    });
```

inside `retrieveData(obj, callback)` you will retrieve `param1` and `param2` with `obj.param1` and `obj.param2`

Answer (score 0):

refactor retrieveData to make param2 optional

```
retrieveData(param1, function(err, result), param2) {
   if (err) throw err;
   // process
```

});